# Does the end of the 2-sliced Loch Ness Monster surface have a fundamental system of neighbourhoods $(V_i)$ such that the frontier of $V_i$ is an arc?

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology, non-orientable-surfaces

Let $S$ be the $2-$sliced Loch Ness Monster surface. Does it end have a fundamental system of neighbourhoods (local base) $(V_i)$ such that the frontier of each $V_i$ is an arc? I was reading a paper by John Mather, "Invariant subsets for area preserving homeomorphisms of surfaces", where he says that every end of a surface with boundary has a fundamental system of neighbourhoods $(V_i)$ such that the frontier of each $V_i$ is a circle or arc. Since $\partial S$ has two connected components, I can't see how this is possible in the case of $S$.

Comment: Can you define "2-sliced Loch Ness Monster surface" and "fundamental system"?

Comment: Fundamental system is also called local base

Comment: For the definition and a nice picture see https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.00564

Comment: Oops sorry, meant to respond earlier!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with a closed arc; sort of a weird neighborhood base in that it's gonna have a slice in it, but it'll do the job.  If you meant open arc, then I guess you could just add a little bit on at the ends.  To do it with the circle is similar.[image]

Just to be clear, the neighborhood is the unbounded component of the complement of the red curve.  You can do it at each handle.

Comment: I think what you were trying to get is some sort of 'regular open' neighborhood, either wrt closure-interior-boundary or with respect to the complement's boundary; it's impossible as far as I can tell, this surface does show that.  At least I couldn't construct it.

Comment: Thanks. I meant closed arcs with the two end points in the boundary of $S$ and the interior of the arc disjoint from the boundary of $S$. Then two arcs are necessary.

Comment: Well yeah, you'll have to cut the bottom sheet and the top sheet *at least*, so you'd need two.  But I don't think it's a counterexample to the Mather theorem.  Can you post the exact statement?  There's no way to do it with a circle by having it not touch the boundary, of course!  It doesn't even make sense in that case, every point is interior to the circle.

Comment: Please give your email so that I can send you a copy of Mather's paper:  Mather, J., Invariant subsets for area preserving homeomorphisms of surfaces, Mathematical Analysis and Applications, Part B, Advances in Mathematics, Supplementary Studies, Vol. 7B, New York: Academic Press, 1981, 531-562.

Comment: Ok!  It's funny; Mather's topological prime end paper was another one I couldn't find and had to get e-mailed to me xD  I dunno what's up with his papers!  Send it to woofwoof@uw.edu  What's the theorem number for this one?